# The fundamental group of a topological space is isomorphic with its connected component fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

can you help me with this problem of fundamental groups?
suppose that $X$ is a topological space, let's fix a point on $X$ like $p\in{X}$. Thus I want to prove that the fundamental group of $X$ at $p$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of connected component of $X$ at $p$.
Should I build a bijection between them and prove its existence? or   should I use theorems of the fundamental theorems and covering spaces... to prove this proposition?
I really need help to solve this problem, thank you all!

Comment: You don't need covering spaces.  Where must the image of a path $\alpha: [0,1] \to X$ live?

Comment: @Randall .thank you for your guidance .the image is in the fundamental group of connected component of $X$

Comment: Yep.  That correspondence gives an iso.

Comment: @pershinaolad I would suggest that you write up an answer to your own question, now that you've figured it out.

Comment: Seconded........